# Jquery regular expression search for turkish characters

Tags: jquery, regex, filter

I have a filter search for my data. When I type turkish characters it doesn't work. How can I modify this code?

```
    var $rows = $('#tableExport tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

These are the characters ç ,ı ,ğ, ö , ş , ü , Ç, İ , Ğ, Ö, Ş, Ü

Comment: Can you post the complete code if possible?

Comment: For example when I search for İç Anadolu it does not show. But the html table contains that value. Or for İstanbul the same.

Comment: Even if when I write Istanbul or Ic Anadolu it doesn't work.

Comment: Please read above comments and provide a live demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, there are two problems: 1) `\b` is not Unicode aware and 2) `i` when used in a case insensitive pattern will only match a dotless `I`, not the dotted counterpart.

I suggest two scenarions: 1) whitespace boundaries, or 2) ASCII word chars + Turkish letters based boundaries.

The patterns are very similar. Here is an example of a whitespace boundary based code:

```
var val = '^(?=.*(?:^|\\s)(?:' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('|') + ')(?!\\S))',
    reg = RegExp(val.replace(/[İi]/ig, '[iİ]'), 'i'),
```

Here, the pattern looks like [`/^(?=.*(?:^|\s)(?:[iİ]ç|Anadolu)(?!\S))/i`](https://regex101.com/r/Q43snr/2). Note that `.replace(/[İi]/ig, '[iİ]')` will allow matching dotted `İ`  with an `i`.

The other approach means we need to replace `\b` with a lookaround that negated an ASCII word char (`\w`) with a Turkish letter:

```
var val = '^(?=.*(?:^|[^\\wçığöşüÇİĞÖŞÜ])(?:' +
    $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).map(function(x) { 
        return x.replace(/[İi]/ig, '[iİ]'); 
    }).join('|') + ')(?![\\wçığöşüÇİĞÖŞÜ]))',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
```

Here, the pattern will look like [`/^(?=.*(?:^|[^\wçığöşüÇİĞÖŞÜ])(?:[iİ]ç|Anadolu)(?![\wçığöşüÇİĞÖŞÜ]))/i`](https://regex101.com/r/Q43snr/1) and will safely match  a term in between non-word or non-Turkish letters.

Answer (score 1):

if you guys are using react or angular must try this one.

const reg = new RegExp(q.toUpperCase().replaceAll(/[İi]/ig, '[iİ]'), 'i')

q could be your object or string that comes from client.